RegularExpressionValidator with optional special characters
I need to validate a field where users have to write a comment. I was asked to allow only alphanumeric characters but this has given some issues with people who still want (reasonably so) to write dots, commas or hyphens. What I wanted to do was to allow those characters but not allow comments made only of such characters. For instance:
Valid: Workers were given gifts (working)

Valid: Part-time workers were given gifts.

Not valid: ...................................

My last regex attempt was [\w\sÑñáéíóú(\.:\-,)?]{20,500}$ (they have to be at least 20 chars long) but it accepts all characters so the third option above also passes the validation in the RegularExpressionValidator.
So, is it possible to accept some extra characters but not validate the field if it only contains those characters?

You could start with a \w before the [...], to force at least a start with a word character

Try:
^(?=.*\w)[\w \tÑñáéíóú(\.:\-,)?]{20,500}$

See: regex101

Explanation

^...$: between start and end of string...
(?=.*\w): look ahead at the string to see if at least one word character is present; make \w a more precise character class as needed.
[\w \tÑñáéíóú(\.:\-,)?]{20,500}: your group, although i replaces \s with   (literal space) and \t tab to exclude newlines. Change back as needed.

